# Javascript IIFE changes result

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, iife

I'm looking at projecteuler.net's 4th problem, and have come across a curious feature that I'm wondering if anyone could explain.

The following code returns 10001

```
var n = 999 * 999; //biggest product with 3 digit numbers
var x;

while (n>10000) { //smallest product of 3 digit numbers
  if (n.toString() === n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) {
    x = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));

    while (n % x !== 0 && x >= 100 && n/x <= 999) {
      x--;
    }

    if (n % x === 0 && x>= 100 && n/x <= 999) {
     n;
    }   
  }
  n--;
}
```

whereas when wrapped in an IIFE, it returns 906609 which is the correct answer.

```
(function euler4() {
var n = 999 * 999; //biggest product with 3 digit numbers
var x;

while (n>10000) { //smallest product of 3 digit numbers
  if (n.toString() === n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) {
    x = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));

    while (n % x !== 0 && x >= 100 && n/x <= 999) {
      x--;
    }

    if (n % x === 0 && x>= 100 && n/x <= 999) {
      return n;
    }

  }
  n--;
}
}());
```

Does anybody know why? I can't find an explanation online. Cheers!

Comment: `n` versus `return n` is probably the culprit.  the first doesn't terminate the function, so it keeps going, but the second does terminate.  What happens if you modify the first code block so it `break;` the loop?

Comment: Right that's exactly it! Adding the break does exactly what I'd hoped, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lone `n` in the first does not terminate the algorithm, whereas the `return n` in the second does. This can be fixed by replacing `n` in the first with a simple `break`

```js
var n = 999 * 999; //biggest product with 3 digit numbers
var x;

while (n>10000) { //smallest product of 3 digit numbers
  if (n.toString() === n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) {
    x = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));

    while (n % x !== 0 && x >= 100 && n/x <= 999) {
      x--;
    }

    if (n % x === 0 && x>= 100 && n/x <= 999) {
     break;
    }   
  }
  n--;
}

console.log(n);
```